# Reading video in matlab

Tags: matlab, video

I have a matlab code that run on my machine but not on our computing cluster. It basically uses mmreader (VideoReader) to read video files. I get the following error on the cluster:

> ??? mmreader requires GStreamer version 0.10.0 or higher on Linux systems.
>   Install the latest Gstreamer 0.10.x release from your Linux distribution or the
>   GStreamer website and restart MATLAB.

I don't have the admin right to install all of the gstreamer packages. Do you know which specific package is needed? I guess I need to install from source. Or is there any other way around it?

Note that the videos are encoded with MPEG v4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least gst-plugins-good and gst-plugins-bad have some MPEG4 codecs. Probably they also have the one(s) you're looking for.

Comment: I could not install gstreamer packages because I didn't have the admin rights. I finally solved my problem using VideoUtils open source package.